# How do I use part of a class as variable using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've got an element like this:

```
<ul class="MainMenu_SubMenu m m0 mid157">
```

I need to get the *mid157* and use that *157* for a variable for something else, i.e:

```
$('SomeOtherElement157')
```

So my question is how do get the class name as a variable and then strip all but the number? The classes are generated so some have more and some have less but they will all have that mid...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var className = $('ul').attr('class'),
    midNum = /\bmid(\S+)/.exec(className)[1],
    selector = 'SomeOtherElement' + midNum;

$(selector);
```

Works for all of the following:

```
<ul class="MainMenu_SubMenu m m0 mid157"></ul>
<ul class="mid158"></ul>
<ul class="mid159 MainMenu_SubMenu m m0"></ul>
<ul class="MainMenu_SubMenu mid160 m m0"></ul>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/P3G8H/

Comment: A `ul` element with the particular element is `a` element in the page and may not be the only `ul` tag. We should rather use the class name or ul + class name combined.

Comment: @Rohan you are 100% correct, but the OP did not provide much information to go on.

Comment: I did end up using more specific selectors but your solution was perfect for what I needed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
var nums = 
    document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0]
                .className.match(/.*mid(\d*)/)[1];

$('selector' + nums);
```

Comment: Wont this return an error if no class 'mid(\d*)' is found?  You would be trying to call [1] on an undefined/null object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grep:

```
var classes=$("div").attr("class").split(" ");

var matches = jQuery.grep(classes, function(n, i){
  return n.indexOf("mid")===0;
});

if(matches[0]){
    var number=matches[0].substring(3);

    // do something with that number 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var patt1   = /mid(\d+)/,
    matches = $('ul').attr('class').match(patt1);

if (matches != undefined && matches[1] != undefined) {
    $('SomeOtherElement'+matches[1]);        
} else {
    alert("No matches.");   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $("div").attr("class").match(/mid([\d]+)/gi)[0].replace("mid", "SomethingElse");

alert(id);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bkSFf/